# What is ESA's Solar Orbiter's target inclination?

Tags: deep-space, the-sun, parker-solar-probe, esa-solar-orbiter

The BBC News article [European SolO probe ready to take on audacious mission](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-50040893) links to the ESA video shown below and contains this [5 minute audio interview with NASA deputy project scientist on the mission Holly Gilbert](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/science-environment-50105205/solo-probe-ready-to-acquire-sharpest-ever-pictures) who outlines several interesting aspects of the mission and complementary measurements with Parker Solar Probe.

She mentions somewhere (I don't have the time code) that the Solar Orbiter will have a view of the Sun's poles, and the video shows what looks like an inclined elliptical orbit.

What inclination are they targeting? I couldn't find any information about that on the ESA page https://sci.esa.int/web/solar-orbiter/ and [this ESA Red Book](https://sci.esa.int/web/solar-orbiter/-/48985-solar-orbiter-definition-study-report-esa-sre-2011-14) is from 2011, so it may not contain up-to-date information.

Comment: companion question: [Will ESA's Solar Orbiter crash into Venus? If so, why?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39449/12102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [inclination will be adjusted](https://sci.esa.int/web/solar-orbiter/-/44181-mission-operations) a few times during the mission:

> The nominal mission of seven years will see a maximum orbital inclination relative to the solar equator of 25°. During the extended mission, additional Venus GAMs could allow the orbital inclination to increase to about 34°. The main scientific activity will take place during the near-Sun encounter and high-latitude parts of each orbit, with different science goals envisioned for each orbit.

Answer (score 1):

From *Solar Orbiter: Exploring the Sun-heliosphere connection* ([ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.4579), [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229329159_Solar_Orbiter_Exploring_the_Sun-Heliosphere_Connection), and published in [Solar Physics](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11207-012-0085-7)) Figure 3 shows the solar latitude of the spacecraft versus time, and the extrema reflect the orbit's inclination **for a January 2017 launch which didn't happen**. While the orbit will be different, this at least illustrates how the inclination was planned to slowly increase over time after each orbit-lowering flyby. (For example, [this paywalled paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/8862/88620E/The-Solar-Orbiter-mission/10.1117/12.2027585.full?SSO=1) lists the launch date as `Jan-2017 (Mar-2017 and Sep-2018 back-ups)`)

```
after flyby        approx. date   approx. inc
-----------        ------------   -----------
  Venus 1            06-2017           7  
  Earth 1            04-2018          14
  Earth 2 + Venus 2  06-2020          17
  Venus 3            04-2022          25
  Venus 4            01-2024          31
  Venus 5            04-2025          34
```

[image]

> Figure 3 Mission profile for a January 2017 launch, showing <s>heliocentric distance (top) and</s> latitude <s>(bottom)</s> of Solar Orbiter as a function of time. Also indicated are the times at which gravity assist maneuvers at
>   Venus and Earth occur (blue).