# What's the highest heliocentric inclination achieved by a deep space probe, without using the outer planets?

Tags: deep-space, record, inclination

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Orbiter) and [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39458/12102) explain that it will take several flyby's of Venus for ESA's Solar Orbiter to reach 34° of inclination.

**Question:** Currently, what's the highest heliocentric inclination achieved by a deep space probe, without using the outer planets (i.e. Jupiter and beyond)? Will Solar orbiter set a new record?

Note that *by using Jupiter* [Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(spacecraft)) achieved a heliocentric inclination of over 79°!

Comment: companion question: [Why did ESA's Solar Orbiter missions' target inclination drop from 34 to 25°?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41312/12102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some candidates:

- The [Deep Impact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Impact_(spacecraft)) spacecraft's impactor, matching Tempel 1's inclination of 10.47 degrees upon collision.
- The [Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) spacecraft, matching Ceres' inclination of 10.59 degrees.
- The [NEAR Shoemaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEAR_Shoemaker) spacecraft, matching 433 Eros' inclination of 10.83 degrees upon landing.

Solar Orbiter is currently beating all of them, at ~14 degrees.